# Adding multiple script dynamically to execute in head and body section in the React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a backend API which provides some javascript code in the **head_script** and **body_script** keys. For example:

```
{
   "head_script": "<script>console.log('abc1')</script><script>console.log('abc2')</script><script>console.log('abc3')</script><script>console.log(abc4')</script>",
   "body_script": "<noscript><iframe src='.......'></iframe></noscript>"
}
```

What i tried to load those script in the head tag is the following and same for body tag also.

```
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + scripts['head_script']
```

I inspected html and saw that those appended in the head and body tags but **found no impact of code**.

Your suggestion will be appreciable. Thanks.

Already described in the previous section

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML`, the scripts are not automatically executed. This is because it does not trigger the browser's built-in script execution mechanism.

However, you may execute a script in page by creating and appending `<script>` tag in document.

```js
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));

const parent = document.head; // or document.body;
parent.appendChild(script);
```

For this, you need to parse `head_script` or `body_script`, collect all scripts and execute the code between `<script>...</script>` tags with above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following these steps:

**Create a script element**

```
let scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
```

**Then add your custom code inside it**

```
scriptEle.text=`console.log('abc1')`;
```

**Finally you should append it to body**

```
document.body.appendChild(scriptEle);
//or
document.head.appendChild(scriptEle);
```

In your case you can extract all script code that receive from API with **Regex**. And Append each one to body for execution.